# Regex to accept no space in date format

Tags: regex

I'm trying to adapt the following pattern to accept also no space in data format DDMMYYYY

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

I've tried to add \S in (/|-|.|\S), but it breaks somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: Try replacing all `(\/|-|\.)` with `([-\/.]?)`.

Comment: ... perhaps without the parentheses, which are now redundant.

Comment: @tripleee parentheses seem to be required since you use that for capturing the separator and later use it for the rest of the regex (so that you may not match things like 01-012018)

Comment: Oh yeah, missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Wiktor Stribizew suggested, replacing all `(\/|-|\.)` by `[-\/.]?` works

Complete expression :

> ^(?:(?:31([-/.]?)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)([-/.]?)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29([-/.]?)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])([-/.]?)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$

Explanation :

`(\/|-|\.)` used to be the patter you use as separation, the patter means "slash OR hyphen OR dot", you want it to be slash OR hyphen OR dot OR nothing"
You could just make the whole group facultative : `(\/|-|\.)?`.
This works but there is a much easier way of writing it : `[-\/.]?`, this matches "(Any hyphen, slash or dot), is facultative"

Comment: [The `(\/|-|\.)?` wouldn't always work](https://regex101.com/r/Qenk7l/1). My solution works with all regex flavors supporting this feature.